# C# WPF: Изменение размера содержимого ячейки вместе с размером колонки DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

У меня такая ситуация: к ячейке `DataGrid` применен шаблон, который содержит `ComboBox`.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ChannelStateCellTemplate">
    <Grid Name="ChannelStateGrid">
        <StackPanel Name="ChannelStateStackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Image Name="channelStateLight" Margin="1" Width="18" Height="18" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <ComboBox Name="channelStateComboBox" Margin="1" ocusable="True" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" FontSize="13" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Данная колонка `DataGrid` может менять ширину. Мне бы хотелось, чтобы `ComboBox` изменял свою ширину, вытягивался вместе с колонкой.
Пробовал делать ширину `Auto` - не помогает. Вообще, предпочтительнее решение через привязку ширины `ComboBox` к ширине колонки через какую либо глобальную переменную, например.

Есть еще темплет для ProgressBar

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ChannelInputLevelCellTemplate">
        <Grid Name="inputLevelGrid">
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" MaxWidth="300" Margin="1" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Label DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="1" Height="Auto" Width="50" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="13" FontWeight="SemiBold" Content="Вход" />
                <ProgressBar Name="inputLevelProgressBar" Margin="2" Height="22" MaxWidth="300" Width="162" VerticalAlignment="Center" Minimum="-60" Maximum="20" Value="{Binding Path=ChannelInLevel, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource ChannelLevelNumberConverter}, Mode=OneWay}">
                </ProgressBar>
                <Label DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="1" Height="Auto" Width="33" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="13" FontWeight="SemiBold" Content="{Binding Path=ChannelInLevel, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource ChannelLevelNumberConverter}}" />
                <Label DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="1" Height="Auto" Width="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="13" FontWeight="SemiBold" Content="дБ" />
            </DockPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: StackPanel не тянется. Замените на DockPanel

Comment: Хорошо. А как настроить привязку размера ComboBox к ширине колонки ?

Comment: Image в Dock="Left", а Combo в остальное  и LastFillChild="True". DockPanel будет тянуться и тянуть содержимое в LastChild которое есть Combo

Comment: А вложенные DockPanel смогут так же тянуться?

Comment: Да. Тянутся DockPanel и Grid. А вообще в целях отладки просто добавьте бэкграунда к элементая и вы визуально увидите кто не хочет тянуться. Только вот на вопрос "почему StackPanel не хочет" у меня ответа нет

Comment: Новая проблема - почему-то не тянется элемент ProgressBar

Comment: Пытаюсь его вставить вместо ComboBox